# Bash script get item from array

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read file line by line in bash.

Every line has format as follows `text|number`.

I want to produce file with format as follows `text,text,text` etc. so new file would have just text from previous file separated by comma.

Here is what I've tried and couldn't get it to work :

```
FILENAME=$1

OLD_IFS=$IFSddd
IFS=$'\n'
i=0
for line in $(cat "$FILENAME"); do
    array=(`echo $line | sed -e 's/|/,/g'`)
    echo ${array[0]}
    i=i+1;
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

But this prints both text and number but in different format `text number`

here is sample input :

```
dsadadq-2321dsad-dasdas|4212
dsadadq-2321dsad-d22as|4322
```

here is sample output:

```
dsadadq-2321dsad-dasdas,dsadadq-2321dsad-d22as
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pure bash, but you could do this in awk:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1{printf(",")} {printf("%s",$1)}'
```

Alternately, in pure bash and without having to strip the final comma:

```
#/bin/bash

# You can get your input from somewhere else if you like. Even stdin to the script.
input=$'dsadadq-2321dsad-dasdas|4212\ndsadadq-2321dsad-d22as|4322\n'

# Output should be reset to empty, for safety.
output=""

# Step through our input.  (I don't know your column names.)
while IFS='|' read left right; do
  # Only add a field if it exists.  Salt to taste.
  if [[ -n "$left" ]]; then
    # Append data to output string
    output="${output:+$output,}$left"
  fi
done <<< "$input"

echo "$output"
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for arrays and `sed`:

```
while IFS='' read line ; do
    echo -n "${line%|*}",
done < "$FILENAME"
```

You just have to remove the last comma :-)

Comment: How would you remove the last comma?  The first thing that comes to mind is `sed`....

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/|[0-9]*\n*/,/g;s/,$//' file
dsadadq-2321dsad-dasdas,dsadadq-2321dsad-d22as
```

Alternatively, here is a bit more readable `sed` with `tr`:

```
$ sed 's/|.*$/,/g' file | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/,$//'
dsadadq-2321dsad-dasdas,dsadadq-2321dsad-d22as
```

Answer (score 0):

Choroba has the best answer (imho) except that it does not handle blank lines and it adds a trailing comma.  Also, mucking with `IFS` is unnecessary.
This is a modification of his answer that solves those problems:

```
while read line ; do
    if [ -n "$line" ]; then
        if [ -n "$afterfirst" ]; then echo -n ,; fi
        afterfirst=1
        echo -n "${line%|*}"
    fi
done < "$FILENAME"
```

The first `if` is just to filter out blank lines.  The second `if` and the `$afterfirst` stuff is just to prevent the extra comma.  It echos a comma before every entry except the first one.  `${line%|\*}` is a bash parameter notation that deletes the end of a paramerter if it matches some expression.  `line` is the paramter, `%` is the symbol that indicates a trailing pattern should be deleted, and `|*` is the pattern to delete.